# Ionic 3 takes too long to start a project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I'm trying to make a new project in ionic using ionic 3. Ever since ionic released ionic 4, they're trying to force me to use ionic 4. I don't have much experience with ionic yet specially ionic 4 so I stick to 3. While making a new project, I'm stuck in this part.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\roxan>cd testIonic

C:\Users\roxan\testIonic>ionic start hellow sidemenu
? The Ionic CLI has an update available (3.4.0 => 4.10.1)! Would you like to install it? No
[OK] Not automatically updating your CLI. You can update manually:

     npm install -g ionic@latest
```

It's been taking forever and I don't know what to do or if it is still in progress. Hoping you could help me. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: its totally based on your Internet speed and your desktop speed also if you want to check all process in detail try this `npm install -g ionic@latest --verbose` will show you all logs of installation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can debug your app in chrome debugger , it is very good to verify which part of  your app is taking time

For the lame workarround you can adjust the splashscreen.hide at some where at the end , like I do.so user would think the app is loading and then the splash screen hide at the end